# How to concatenate multiple rows to single row without messing up the data?

Tags: xml, nested, concatenation, sql-server-2014, coalesce

I am new to sql server and found a problem in using the FOR XML code.
My report builder is using sql server 2014.

I have the table like:

| Field | Accessory |
| --- | --- |
| 1.I | AA |
| 1.I | BB |
| 1.I | CC |
| 1.II | AA |
| 1.III | AA |
| 1.III | BB |
| 1.IV | AA |
| 1.IV | BB |
| 1.V | AA |

And the result requires to be:

| Field | Accessory |
| --- | --- |
| 1.I | AA,BB,CC |
| 1.II | AA |
| 1.III | AA,BB |
| 1.IV | AA,BB |
| 1.V | AA |

But instead, I’ve got this:

| Field | Accessory |
| --- | --- |
| 1.I | AA,BB,CC,AA,AA,BB,AA,BB,AA |
| 1.II | AA,BB,CC,AA,AA,BB,AA,BB,AA |
| 1.III | AA,BB,CC,AA,AA,BB,AA,BB,AA |
| 1.IV | AA,BB,CC,AA,AA,BB,AA,BB,AA |
| 1.V | AA,BB,CC,AA,AA,BB,AA,BB,AA |

Is it appropriate to use FOR XML path for this kind of table grouping?
Thanks!

The query is :

```
SELECT
       Radi.Field,
       (SELECT
               Acce.AccessoryId+','
        FROM
               FieldAcce
               INNER JOIN Radi ON FieldAcce.RadiSer = Radi.RadiSer
               INNER JOIN Acce ON FieldAcce.AcceSer = Acce.AcceSer
        WHERE
               Radi.Id LIKE UPPER (@RNO)
               AND Radi.CourseID LIKE @CourseID
               AND Radi.PhaseId LIKE @PhaseID
        ORDER BY
               Radi.Field
        FOR XML PATH('')) AS [Accessory]
FROM
        FieldAcce
        INNER JOIN Radi ON FieldAcce.RadiSer = Radi.RadiSer
        INNER JOIN Acce ON FieldAcce.AcceSer = Acce.AcceSer
WHERE
        Radi.Id LIKE UPPER (@RNO)
        AND Radi.CourseID LIKE @CourseID
        AND Radi.PhaseId LIKE @PhaseID
GROUP BY
        Radi.Field
        Acce.AccessoryId
ORDER BY
        Radi.Field
```

The new query is as followed (It works when the STUFF() part have not added):

```
SELECT
    r.Field,
    STUFF(  
        (SELECT
            ', ' + Acce.AccessoryId
         FROM
            Radi
            INNER JOIN FieldAcce ON Radi.RadiSer = FieldAcce.RadiSer
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Acce ON FieldAcce.AcceSer = Acce.AcceSer
         WHERE
            Radi.Id LIKE UPPER (@RNO)
            AND Radi.CourseId LIKE @CourseID
            AND LEFT (Radi.PlanSetupId,1) LIKE @PhaseID
            AND r.Field = Radi.Field
         ORDER BY
            Radi.Field
         FOR XML PATH(''))
          ), 1, 1, '') AS [Accessory]
FROM
    Radi r
    INNER JOIN FieldAcce ON r.RadiSer = FieldAcce.RadiSer
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Acce ON FieldAcce.AcceSer = Acce.AcceSer
WHERE
    Radi.Id LIKE UPPER (@RNO)
    AND Radi.CourseId LIKE @CourseID
    AND LEFT (Radi.PlanSetupId,1) LIKE @PhaseID
    AND EXISTS
        (SELECT
            r.Field
         FROM
            Radi cry
         WHERE
            r.Field = cry.Field
            AND cry.Field NOT LIKE N'APER%')
GROUP BY
    r.Field
ORDER BY
    r.Field
```

Sample data for Accessory is

| Accessory |
| --- |
| EDW45IN |
| A10 |
| A06 |
| EDW60IN |
| EDW45OUT |
| NDS |
| A084 |

Comment: Please show us your query

Comment: Do I need to show the full query or just a simplified one?

Comment: Just blogged about this... today. https://sqlperformance.com/2022/02/t-sql-queries/string-aggregation-over-the-years-in-sql-server

Comment: Thanks Aaron! I have posted the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sub-query should reference the main query `Field` and `AccessoryId`

```
SELECT
       Radi.Field,
       (SELECT
               a.AccessoryId+','
        FROM
               FieldAcce fa
               INNER JOIN Radi r ON fa.RadiSer = r.RadiSer
               INNER JOIN Acce a ON fa.AcceSer = a.AcceSer
        WHERE
               r.Id LIKE UPPER (@RNO)
               AND r.CourseID LIKE @CourseID
               AND r.PhaseId LIKE @PhaseID
               -- add the following 2 lines
               AND r.Field = Radi.Field
               AND a.AccessoryId = Acce.AccessoryId
        ORDER BY
               r.Field
        FOR XML PATH('')) AS [Accessory]
FROM
        FieldAcce
        INNER JOIN Radi ON FieldAcce.RadiSer = Radi.RadiSer
        INNER JOIN Acce ON FieldAcce.AcceSer = Acce.AcceSer
WHERE
        Radi.Id LIKE UPPER (@RNO)
        AND Radi.CourseID LIKE @CourseID
        AND Radi.PhaseId LIKE @PhaseID
GROUP BY
        Radi.Field,
        Acce.AccessoryId
ORDER BY
        Radi.Field
```

Comment: And now I have a following question…. I used STUFF( to remove the leading comma but it shows error saying I didnt have 4 arguments and incorrect syntax before GROUP. How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: please show your latest query. You must have missed out comma or parenthesis somewhere

Comment: Also It will be easier for others to verify your query if you can provide the schema and sample data from each of the tables

Comment: I have posted the latest query and the sample data but I'm not sure about the schema.

Comment: You have one extra `)` after the `FOR XML PATH`. Also in the `WHERE` clause, change all reference from `Radi` to table alias `r`. Example `Radi.Id` to `r.Id`

Comment: THANKS!!! That extra ) really caught me!! Problem solved :-).